# VariableDoesNotExist at /list/ Failed lookup for key [nodes] in u"[

Tags: python, django, django-mptt

I'm having problem with Django MPTT 
my models is

```
class Catalog(MPTTModel):
name = models.CharField(verbose_name='name',max_length=256,blank=True  )
name_slug = models.CharField(verbose_name='Name_slug',max_length=250,blank=True)
parent = TreeForeignKey('self',null=True,blank=True,related_name='children')

class MPTTMeta:
    order_insertion_by = ['name']
def __unicode__(self):
    return u"%s %s %s " %(self.name,self.name_slug,self.parent)
def __str__(self):
    return u"%s %s %s " %(self.name,self.name_slug,self.parent
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("catalog",kwargs={"slug":self.name_slug})
```

Now, I use MPTT in base.html, like this:

```
<ul class="root">
{% recursetree nodes %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ node.get_absolute_url }}">{{ node.name }}</a>
        {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
            <ul class="children">
                <a href="{{ children.get_absolute_url }}">{{ children }}</a>
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endrecursetree %}
```

However when I go to my page with mptt tree I can see:

```
VariableDoesNotExist at /list/
Failed lookup for key [nodes] in u"[{'False': False, 'None': None, 'True': True}, {}, {}, {'places': <QuerySet [<Place: \u041b\u044c\u0432\u0456\u0432 lvv \u0441\u0456\u0456\u0441\u0441\u0456\u0441\u0456\u0456\u0441 list.Catalog.None >, <Place: \u0421\u043a\u0430\u043b\u0430\u0442 skalat \u0421\u043a\u0430\u043b\u0430\u0442 list.Catalog.None >]>}]"
```

Can you tell me where is my problem?

Comment: Can you put your _views_ in question?

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget that with the example `{% recursetree nodes %}`, `nodes` is actually the name of your categories template variable.

So if your `views.py` sends the categories object to the template as `categories`, then you need to use `{% recursetree categories %}` instead.

Within the `recursetree` block, `node` is hardcoded to the individual node of the tree and `children` is hardcoded to the children of that node, but `nodes` is just an example template variable name.